# how to achieve a polymorphism like creation of an angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a table directive that will receive a row type as a parameter.

Assuming the use of the table directive should look something like:

```
<my-table items="collection" row-type="blueRow"></my-table>
```

and the template would be something like:

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
     <my-row type="vm.rowType"></my-row>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And that way anybody can use that table, and "inject" the specific row type they want into the table directive.

How do I make myRow tag to be the type of directive which the users passe when they create the table? 
I tried using transclude like this:

```
<my-table items="collection">
     <my-row>
         <td class="blue-row">this is my blue row</td>
     <my-row>
</my-table>
```

and in the table directive template (Obviously with the right adjustments to the directive .js):

```
 <table>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
     <div ng-transclude="row"></div>
   </tr>
</table>
```

But it does not work.

Would really appreciate your help! 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle ?

Comment: WIll try to create one